# Replace a control on the screen

Tags: iphone

I have an instance of a FlowCoverView (a great library that emulates cover flow on the iPhone).  And it works great, with the exception of an update.  When I update my table behind the scenes, I have no way of telling this control (that is defined in IB) that it has been updated, and to reload.  (much like you can with a table using reloadData)

To the question, is there a way to replace a control that is on the screen with another control to force the reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that the implementation of the following protocol methods of the `FlowCoverViewDelegate` reflect the changes of your data.

```
- (UIImage *)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view cover:(int)cover;
- (int)flowCoverNumberImages:(FlowCoverView *)view;
```

Comment: this got me closer, the control is asking for the 4th image in the series, so it is assuming that I added to the end of the set.  The new image is set the first item in the array.  Is there a way to tell the control to reload all of it's data?

Comment: You might also want to add a method to FlowCoverView to clean the dataCache and the current position if needed. Also, there's another method of the protocol that you should take into account. See edited answer.